# PowerShell - copying multiple files

Tags: powershell, backup, file-copying

I've written a PowerShell script to copy new files across to a shared folder on a server.

I am wondering if there is a way that after I get the list of new files in the sub folders, I can copy them over together - other than using for-each and copying them one at a time - so that I can add a progress bar.

Comment: But it's easier to provide a progress bar with foreach-object; `$files | foreach { Write-Progress -Activity "Copying" -PercentComplete (($index++)/$files.count)*100; copy $_ "\\server\destination" }`

Comment: Thanks TessellatingHeckler

I wasn't sure if that would work as a previous search turned up using the .Net copyhere method to copy via windows explorer and get the progress bar that way which is what I'm doing at the moment inside the foreach loop which currently results in a progress bar for each file.

Ill give this a try thanks

Answer (score 0):

something like this could be a starting point

```
# define source and destination folders
$source = 'C:\temp\music'
$dest = 'C:\temp\new'

# get all files in source (not empty directories)
$files = Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse -File

$index = 0
$total = $files.Count
$starttime = $lasttime = Get-Date
$results = $files | % {
    $index++
    $currtime = (Get-Date) - $starttime
    $avg = $currtime.TotalSeconds / $index
    $last = ((Get-Date) - $lasttime).TotalSeconds
    $left = $total - $index
    $WrPrgParam = @{
        Activity = (
            "Copying files $(Get-Date -f s)",
            "Total: $($currtime -replace '\..*')",
            "Avg: $('{0:N2}' -f $avg)",
            "Last: $('{0:N2}' -f $last)",
            "ETA: $('{0:N2}' -f ($avg * $left / 60))",
            "min ($([string](Get-Date).AddSeconds($avg*$left) -replace '^.* '))"
        ) -join ' '
        Status = "$index of $total ($left left) [$('{0:N2}' -f ($index / $total * 100))%]"
        CurrentOperation = "File: $_"
        PercentComplete = ($index/$total)*100
    }
    Write-Progress @WrPrgParam
    $lasttime = Get-Date

    # build destination path for this file
    $destdir = Join-Path $dest $($(Split-Path $_.fullname) -replace [regex]::Escape($source))

    # if it doesn't exist, create it
    if (!(Test-Path $destdir)) {
        $null = md $destdir
    }

    # if the file.txt already exists, rename it to file-1.txt and so on
    $num = 1
    $base = $_.basename
    $ext = $_.extension
    $newname = Join-Path $destdir "$base$ext"
    while (Test-Path $newname) {
        $newname = Join-Path $destdir "$base-$num$ext"
        $num++
    }

    # log the source and destination files to the $results variable
    Write-Output $([pscustomobject]@{
        SourceFile = $_.fullname
        DestFile = $newname
    })

    # finally, copy the file to its new location
    copy $_.fullname $newname
}

# export a list of source files
$results | Export-Csv c:\temp\copylog.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

NOTE: that will show progress for total files regardless of size. ex: you have 2 files, one is 1 mb and the other is 50 mb. when the first file is copied, progress will be 50% because half the files are copied. if you want progress by total bytes, i highly recommend giving this function a try. just give it a source and destination. works when given a single file or a whole folder to copy

https://github.com/gangstanthony/PowerShell/blob/master/Copy-File.ps1

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4H14.png

Comment: Thanks Anthony 
Ill take a look at the function